# One Service class method call in other service class method - spring IOC+ Struts 2

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, struts2

Is it recommended to call one service layer class method in other service layer class method using delegate?

I am using Struts 2 framework + Spring IOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common that one service class uses other service classes to fulfill its functionality.

Comment: @Mangesh Jogade: That a DAO invoke a Service is often permitted by the software architect, because if a DAO needs to call a service, then this is a indication that the DAO contains business logic. But a DAO should be free of business logic, business logic should be implemented only in the service layer.